# Pilloni's cohomological corrispondence factorization

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, automorphic-forms, hida-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 7.1.1 at page 39 of [Pilloni's paper](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/vincent.pilloni/complexhidatheorygsp4.pdf) on Higher Hida and Coleman Theory for $GSp_4$. In particular, what is not clear to me is the diagram relating Serre-Tate's parameters:

[image]

My questions are:

1. How do we get the diagonal matrix on the left?
2. Assuming he is using the identification as in page 160 of [Katz's paper](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enmk/old/serretatelocmod.pdf), why do we get a $p$ multiplying $Z'$ in the bottom matrix? I expected this matrix to be symmetric, as the upper one is.
3. The matrix on the right is also not clear.

Thank you in advance!